# MySQL JOIN query phrasing

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables.

And I could use some help putting together a JOIN query.

Table 1: works
This is my main table.
It contains a lot of different fields, including a unique, primary key.
And it contains a “composers_id” field - which relates to next table.

Table 2: composers
This table contains additional information on the composers for the works in the “Works” table.
It contains many fields aswell, including a unique primary key - this is the id that “works” relates to.

Table 3: works_instruments
This table contains additional info about the instruments in the works.
It contains unique primary key.
And it contains a “works_id” field that relates to the unique id in the “works” table.
There are several rows all relating to each “works_id” - because there is a lot of info about each instrument, in every work.

Here’s the deal:
I need to be able to search for results in the works table, but only results that match criteria that can only be checked in the works_instruments table.

I am thinking something like this:

```
"SELECT
    works.id,
    works.title

FROM works

    JOIN composers

        ON works.composers_id = composers.id"
```

But then what if I need to only get results from the works table - if there is a flute in one the rows of the relevant "works_id"s?
The “works_instruments” contains, besides the “works_id” field, an “instrument” field, that may and may not contain the word “flute”. 
There will be many rows with the same “works_id”. For instance: 1 row for “flute” in the “instrument” field and another row with “Bass” in the “instrument” field. - And so on.

How do I do the query so that I only get works from the works table, if there is a a flute involved?

Can you help?

Thank you in advance
John

Edit:

This is the works table:

```
CREATE TABLE `works` (
 `id` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `composers_id` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `work_no` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `composer_no` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `composers_full_name` tinytext,
 `full_title` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `short_title` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `alternative_titles` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `remarks` text NOT NULL,
 `contents` text NOT NULL,
 `first_line` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `full_inst_ed4_rev4` text NOT NULL,
 `duration` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `sourcetext` text NOT NULL,
 `chor_acc_size` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `youth_commentary` text NOT NULL,
 `youth_category_rev` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `orchestra_type` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `creation_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `master_title_opas` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `short_name` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `url` tinytext,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `composers_id` (`composers_id`),
 KEY `url` (`url`(16)),
 FULLTEXT KEY `keywords` (`composers_full_name`,`full_title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8183 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This is the composers table:

```
CREATE TABLE `composers` (
 `id` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `composer_no` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `name` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `short_name` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `birth_year` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `death_year` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `vitae` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `catalog` text NOT NULL,
 `classification` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `comment` text NOT NULL,
 `gender` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `alerts` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `corrected` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `creation_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `edition` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `first_name` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `full_name` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `last_name` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `modification_date` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `name_accented` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `short_name_accented` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `vitae_accented` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `url` tinytext,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`(16))
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_

INCREMENT=1197 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And this is the works_instruments table:

```
CREATE TABLE `works_instruments` (
 `works_id` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `instruments_id` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `number` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `numbertext` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `detail` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `printout` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `editable` tinytext NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `works_instruments` (`works_id`,`instruments_id`),
 KEY `works_id` (`works_id`),
 KEY `instruments_id` (`instruments_id`),
 KEY `number` (`number`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

("instruments_id" is what I previously called "instrument")

Comment: is `works_instruments ` nicely defined, or is it a de-normalized mess? Where is the `instruments` table, so the `wi` table is a junction table concept

Comment: I suspect that this question could be more long-winded, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: I recommend you show your schema with the likes of `show create table xxx` for each xxx, so peeps can give it a friendly scrutiny before you jam it full of stuff. Over and out. Close vote recorded. Start typing

Comment: Im not sure I quite understand your question, Drew? But yes, I do believe the works table is nicely defined.
The instruments table is called works_instruments.... was that what you were asking?

Comment: You mean a dump of the table structure?

Comment: I am very much a newbee here. I dont know what you mean when you say "do a show create"?

Comment: `show create table <tablename>` is a (My)Sql command

Comment: oh! ok. Sure. Hang on.

Comment: this format is useful: [Pastie](http://pastie.org/10525488), this format is not: png, gif, human-described. And of course put it in an [edit] to your question, not in a Pastie or in comments

Comment: Edit added. With what I hope was what you asked for?

Comment: Is that the question: "I want all instruments with the name 'flute' from all works of a given composer."?

Comment: Yes. I would probably turn it around, but I guess it doesnt make any difference: "I want all works, using the instrument "flute", from a given composer.

Comment: And thank you for cleaning up my question, Axel. Makes perfect sense. I'm learning.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simpler than I thought.

I just added another JOIN to include the works_instruments with the correct works_id
and then a WHERE clause, to make sure the correct instrument is included.

So it looks something like this:

```
"SELECT
    works.id,
    works.title

FROM works

    JOIN composers

        ON works.composers_id = composers.id

    JOIN works_instruments

        ON works.id = works_instruments.works_id

WHERE works_instruments.instrument_id = the instruemnt id I am asking for"
```

This seem to be working just fine.

I apologize to have wasted your time, actually being able to do it myself. 
I guess I just didn't trust myself to be able to it. :-)